# Vue - Property "character" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: vuejs3

I have a js object that I want to share with multiple components so I imported the object in the parent component and tried to pass it down to the children with v-bind.

When I render, I get returned

[Vue warn]: Property "character" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
at <CharacterStats character=
Object { name: "Dorito Stilltoes", race: "Mountain Dwarf", level: 6, class: "Battle Smith", stats: (6) […] }

> 

at 
at

What am I doing wrong?

Parent Component

```
<script setup>
  import character from '../assets/data/dorito';
  import characterStats from './characterStats.vue'

</script>

<template>
  <body>
    <characterStats :character="character"></characterStats>
  </body>
</template>

<style>
</style>
```

Child Component

```
<script>
</script>
    
<template>
    <h1>{{ character }}</h1>
</template>
<style></style>
```

Object

```
const dorito = {
        name:"Dorito Stilltoes",
        race:"Mountain Dwarf",
        level:6,
        class:"Battle Smith",
        stats:[16,12,16,16,13,11]
}

export default dorito
```

I tried passing down an object from my parent component to my child component, my expectations were that I can import the object once in my parent and then have it shared to the children instead of importing it on each child.

Following tutorials and the docs from Vue.js I used the v-bind method, but I am only getting [Vue warn]: Property "character" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. in return.

I don't understand were I am going wrong as this seemed simple and straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76026930/17811563).

For a more ergonomic syntax, you can also use Composition API with SFC:

```js
<script setup>
import { defineProps } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  character: Object,
});
</script>

<template>
  <section>
    {{ props.character }}
  </section>
</template>
```

This way you don't need to use `export`. However, you will design your components *slightly different* compared to the standard Composition API. I recommend you read more about this [here](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html).

> Following tutorials and the docs from Vue.js I used the v-bind method, but I am only getting [Vue warn]: Property "character" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.

The purpose of `v-bind` for props is to dynamically assign the properties of an object to the component. You can think of it as like the object spread operator but for Vue components:

```js
// Parent Component
<script setup>
  import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue';

  const character = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 45,
  };
</script>

<template>
  <section>
    <ChildComponent v-bind="character" />
  </section>
</template>
```

```js
// Child Component
<script setup>
  import { defineProps } from 'vue';

  const props = defineProps({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
  });
</script>

<template>
  <article>
    {{ props.name }} - {{ props.age }}
  </article>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. My problem was that I was not declaring the props in my child component. I find it strange that I have to decalre an export when I am importing.

Child Component correctcode.

```
    <script>
    export default {
        name: 'MainPage',
        props: ['character']
    }
</script>
    
<template>
    <h5>{{ character.name }}</h5>
</template>
<style></style>
```